# How to subset a dataframe in r using placeholder

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe with different variables. For example:

```
 x10 <- c(1, 2, 3)
 x11 <- c(3, 2, 1)
 x12 <- c(1, 2, 3)

 y05_p <- c(5, 6, 7)
 y06_p <- c(4, 5, 6)
 y07_p <- c(3, 4, 5)

 dat <- data.frame(x10, x11, x12, y05_p, y06_p, y07_p)

 > dat
   x10 x11 x12 y05_p y06_p y07_p
 1   1   3   1     5     4     3
 2   2   2   2     6     5     4
 3   3   1   3     7     6     5
```

Now i would like to drop some variables, but with specific conditions: For example, all variables called "x", no matter what number following. In other words: I want to use a "placeholder", to drop every variable, that includes "x" in the name.

Using subset, this could look like:

```
 dat <- subset(dat, select = -c(x*))
```

Here, the "*" is the placeholder.

Or just with "select":

```
 dat <- select(dat, -x*)
```

The result should look like:

```
 dat <- select(dat, -x*)

 > dat
   y05_p y06_p y07_p
 1     5     4     3
 2     6     5     4
 3     7     6     5
```

Or to work with another example:

```
 dat <- select(dat, -y*_p)

 > dat
   x10 x11 x12
 1   1   3   1
 2   2   2   2
 3   3   1   3
```

I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `starts_with()`.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% select(-starts_with("x"))
```

There are other functions like this (`ends_with`, `matches`, `contains`, `one_of`). And if everything else fails, you can always use regular expressions and base R:

```
dat <- dat[ , !grepl("^x", colnames(dat)) ]
```

Explanation: `grepl` returns a logical vector. The regular expression `"^x"` matches anything that starts with an `x`. This is matched against the column names of dat. We negate the logical vector with the bang (`!`) and thus select everything that does not match our regex.

Comment: For those without all of `tidyverse` installed, `library(dplyr)` is all that is needed for the first code block.

Comment: Not really, AFAIK the pipe operator is exported from `magrittr`.

Comment: `magrittr::%>%` is re-exported by `dplyr`, so `library(dplyr)` alone (without `library(magrittr)`) suffices. (Clarification: I said `library(dplyr)` is needed ... I did not say `dplyr` is the only package needed, though technically you cannot have `dplyr` without `magrittr`.)

Comment: I think I see your point, but `tidyverse` not being installed has nothing to do with `dplyr` availability. Mostly it's a "style" thing, so it's just my suggestion. (It is *just a little bit* "mwe" thing, something we encourage in our questions. But mostly style, most definitely not a requirement.)

Answer (score 4):

Use `grep` and its argument `invert = TRUE`

```
placeholder <- "x"
idx <- grep(pattern = placeholder, names(dat), invert = TRUE)
dat[idx]
  y05_p y06_p y07_p
1     5     4     3
2     6     5     4
3     7     6     5
```

If the pattern is that you want to exclude columns that start with "x" use `startsWith`

```
idx <- !startsWith(names(dat), prefix = placeholder)
```